# Git status does not show changes when creating repo in JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I was trying JGit, for project like

```
      sample--
             |-- src
                   |---sampletest
                          |------Test.txt
```

I make this git project by `repo.create()` in JGit, and I can find .git inside sample. But whenever I modified the Test.txt. It was not displayed in git status from terminal.

I am unable to figure out the answer.

Also is there any other Java API that can be used?

**EDIT**

This project does not have .git intially.
I did,

```
repository = new FileRepository(<somepath>/sample/+".git");
     git = new Git(repository);
```

This creates a .git inside sample. 
Git status from terminal:

```
C:\Users\msrivastava\Documents\GitHub\sample> git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So After repo.create(), it does not add or commit the sample/src/*

After all this I load the sample project git repo. And perform add with file pattern "src/*" and "src/sampletest/Test.txt"

```
repository = new FileRepository(<somepath>/sample/+".git");
        git = new Git(repository);
git.add().addFilePattern("src/*").call();
```

Also

```
git.add().addFilePattern("src/sampletest/Text.txt").call();
```

Git status from terminal after this:

```
C:\Users\msrivastava\Documents\GitHub\sample [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: I can see changes in a repository created by JGit with 'git status' without problems. From which directory did you call 'git status'? Can you try the same scenario with a repository created by command-line Git, does the status command work then?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: I updated the question with more details. And I am still not getting correct status.

Comment: Also , when I did git add src/* from terminal, it works. But its not working from JGit lib

Comment: The first `git status` output is OK - you haven't added anything, thus 'src' is untracked.

If command line Git doesn't reflect the `add` calls, it might be that the JGit Repository object operates on a different directory. Did you check what `repo.getWorkingDir()` and `getDirectory()` returns? What does `git.status().call().getAdded()` return?

BTW (probably unrelated) the JGit `AddCommand` does not support wildcards yet (see the JavaDoc). Use `addFilepattern( "." )` to add _everything_.

Comment: @Mohyt I am facing the same issue, due you manage to get it run. Working directory is /.git location

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart of `git status` in JGit is the `StatusCommand`. It can be obtained from the *Git command factory* and called like so:

```
    Repository repo = ...
    Git git = Git.wrap( repo );
    Status status = git.status().call();
```

The getters of `Status` return the paths of the added, removed, modified, tracked, etc. files.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I am getting empty array as describe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748442/jgitbare-repository-has-neither-a-working-tree-nor-an-index-with-existing-repo