# Jgit:Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index with existing repository

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have an existing repository and trying to point to the existing repository and getting an exception as

```
Jgit:Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
```

Using the existing repository

```
public static Repository GetRepository(String destinationDirectory) throws IOException {
    Repository existingRepo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir(new File(destinationDirectory))
            .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
            .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
            .build();
    return existingRepo;
}
```

trying to get the status of the repository

```
public static void GitStatus(Repository repository) throws GitAPIException {
    
    try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
        Status status = git.status().call();
        System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
        System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
        System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
        System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
        System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
        System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
        System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
        System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
        System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
        System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.getIndexFile(Repository.java:1147)
```

**File directory**
[image]

Comment: You cannot call `git.status()` on a bare repository. Either your repository is actually a bare repository or possibly your `FileRepositoryBuilder` code picks the wrong repository. Use `Repository::getDirectory` to see which repository is actually referenced.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann well it us pointing to the correct one, update the screenshot on the question, please have a look

Comment: For non-bare repos, `Repository::getDirectory` points to the `.git` directory of the repo. This isn't the case here. Make sure that your `destinationDirectory` argument actually points to the `.git` directory of the repo. See also here for a in-depth discussion of JGit's APIs to open repos: https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Now the destinationDirectory is pointing to the .git directory, but there is no changes status everything is empty. I am getting all as empty Added: []
Changed: []
Conflicting: []
ConflictingStageState: {}
IgnoredNotInIndex: [database/.DS_Store, .DS_Store]
Missing: []
Modified: []
Removed: []. However, with the git status on terminal I can see there is database folder unstage